# Code looping when I don't need it to, hard to explain in title

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a progress checklist for the game Final Fantasy X-2.

What I have is this:

The Label names "Luca - +1.6" is label1. Under that is CheckedListBox1, then Label2, CheckedListBox2 and so on.

What should happen is, when every item in a CheckedListBox (CLB for short) is
checked, the CLB and Label above should have it's font changed to strikeout
and trim the Label.Text to just the number and add that to the TabPage1.Text.

The problem I have is this: I check both item is CLB1, the CLB and label get struckout, and TabPage1.Text is changed to "Chapter 1 - 1.6". Now when I check **ONE** item in CLB2, 1.6 get added to TabPage1.Text making it 3.2. That repeats with every item I check.

I think I know whats causing the problem, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I would like to keep the code condensed, and not have say 20 If statements for each CLB.

My code is below and an image is linked.

[Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6H5r.png)

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, CheckedListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim CLmatches() As Control
    Dim LBmatches() As Control
    For a As Integer = 1 To TabPage1.Controls.Count
        CLmatches = Me.Controls.Find("CheckedListBox" & a, True)
        If CLmatches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf CLmatches(0) Is CheckedListBox Then
            Dim cl As CheckedListBox = DirectCast(CLmatches(0), CheckedListBox)
            If cl.CheckedItems.Count = cl.Items.Count Then
                'CheckBox1.Checked = True
                cl.Font = New Font(cl.Font, cl.Font.Style Or FontStyle.Strikeout)
                LBmatches = Me.Controls.Find("Label" & a, True)
                If LBmatches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf LBmatches(0) Is Label Then
                    Dim lb = DirectCast(LBmatches(0), Label)
                    lb.Font = New Font(lb.Font, lb.Font.Style Or FontStyle.Strikeout)
                    Dim test As String = lb.Text
                    Dim phrase As String = test.Substring(test.IndexOf("+"c) + 1)
                    percentage += phrase
                    TabPage1.Text = "Chapter 1 - " & percentage & "%"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another bug caused by global variables (and a classic one)

You should set the global variable *percentage* to zero before starting any of this code. If you click more than one time on the CheckedListBoxes your *percentage* always increases from the value calculated in the previous event at this line

```
percentage += phrase
```

regardless of what the other checkedlistbox status is.
Also you should set the TabPage1.Text just one time before exiting from the event handler.

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(.....)....

    Dim CLmatches() As Control
    Dim LBmatches() As Control
    percentage = 0
    For a As Integer = 1 To TabPage1.Controls.Count
       .....
    Next
    TabPage1.Text = "Chapter 1 - " & percentage & "%"
End Sub
```

In this mode the calc is always correct even if you uncheck some of your checkeditems

A point that is not possible to answer now is if you really need this variable to be a global class level one. If possible try to avoid global class variables.

Comment: I could have sworn i tried this, whatever, your amazing.